# WSO2 APIM Install and Deployment HTTP 500 on /services/

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We're trying to deploy WSO2 to our cloud environment. I used the provided [cloudformation templates](https://github.com/wso2/aws-apim) to deploy to AWS. I try to access the Carbon Server UI but I receive a 500 error code.

When I look in wso2carbon.log I see this error correlated with the request that generates a 500 error code.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-03-15 18:14:10,356] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/].[bridgeservlet]} - Servlet.service(
) for servlet [bridgeservlet] in context with path [/] threw exception org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doGet(CarbonServlet.java:157)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.owasp.csrfg
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.synapse.api.ApiUtils.getFullRequestPath(ApiUtils.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.DefaultAPIHandler.handleRequestInFlow_aroundBody0(DefaultAPIHandler.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.DefaultAPIHandler.handleRequestInFlow(DefaultAPIHandler.java:41)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.invokeHandlers(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:1173)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:101)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:139)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:852)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.handleRestRequest(CarbonServlet.java:312)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doGet(CarbonServlet.java:154)
        ... 50 more
```

I believe this means that there is no API to request which is passing a null value that is trying to be de-referenced later. But, I'm not sure if that's correct.

Any help understanding the error would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have mapped the wrong ports. Management console, admin services and all the UI components(Devportal, Publisher) etc. are exposed via port `9443`. The Gateway(API calls) are exposed via ports `8243` for HTTPS and `8280` for HTTP traffic. Hence check the port mappings in your Loadbalancer.